# How to show tooltip in code behind in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, tooltip

How can I show a tooltip in code-behind? The code below defines my question better. Obviously I don't want the code to check for mouse position etc, just how to display the tooltip.

```
private void UIElement_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // if mouse position equals certain coordinates show the tooltip
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try like this:

```
if (control.ToolTip != null)
{
    // Main condition
    if (control.ToolTip is ToolTip)
    {
        var castToolTip = (ToolTip)control.ToolTip;
        castToolTip.IsOpen = true;
    }
    else
    {
        toolTip.Content = control.ToolTip;
        toolTip.StaysOpen = false;
        toolTip.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

The `Main condition` necessary, because `ToolTip` for Control can be set in two approaches:

**`First approach`**

```
<Button Name="TestButton"
        ToolTip="TestToolTip" />
```

This approach is most common. In this case, the content of the ToolTip will object and not type of `ToolTip`.

**`Second approach`**

```
<Button Name="TestButton"
        Content="Test">

    <Button.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip>TestToolTip</ToolTip>
    </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

Is the same as this:

```
<Button Name="TestButton"
        Content="Test">

    <Button.ToolTip>
        TestToolTip
    </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

In this case, the Content type of ToolTip will be `Tooltip`. Note that in the second case, the object automatically fills ToolTip object on line `TestToolTip`, hence this approach will work a bit slower.

Therefore, this check is needed to avoid an exception when we try to assign to the ToolTip the content of the `ToolTip` type here:

```
toolTip.Content = control.ToolTip;
```

Below is a full example:

`XAML`

```
<Grid>
    <Button Name="TestButton"
            Width="100"
            Height="25"
            Content="Test" 
            ToolTip="TestToolTip" />

    <Button Name="ShowToolTip" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Content="ShowToolTip" 
            Click="ShowToolTip_Click" />
</Grid>
```

`Code-behind`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ShowToolTip_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var toolTip = new ToolTip();

        if (TestButton.ToolTip != null)
        {
            if (TestButton.ToolTip is ToolTip)
            {
                var castToolTip = (ToolTip)TestButton.ToolTip;
                castToolTip.IsOpen = true;
            }
            else
            {
                toolTip.Content = TestButton.ToolTip;
                toolTip.StaysOpen = false;
                toolTip.IsOpen = true;
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this gives me nullrefrenceexception.

Comment: Thanks it worked for the button but it is not working for the MouseMove event on Canvas

Comment: @Vahid: What exactly does not work? Show is full not working example.

Comment: As I've included in my question I want to display the Tooltip when I move the mouse on Canvas and reach a certain point. But the information you gave me will be enough for the rest of the journey. Thanks