# Can WPF UIElement show Tooltip without MouseOver?

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to display a ToolTip of an element if mouse/keyboard hasnt actually moved over that element? I know, that Popup would sound proper solution for that, but for my form I want to have ToolTips displayed over elements, few per time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show tooltip in code behind in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041768/how-to-show-tooltip-in-code-behind-in-wpf)

Comment: Could you reformat the tile in the form of a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to display a `ToolTip` of an element if mouse/keyboard hasnt actually moved over that element?

Yes, the `ToolTip` has an `IsOpen` property that you can set:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tb" Text="..." xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip IsOpen="True" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=tb}"
                 HorizontalOffset="100" VerticalOffset="100">
            <TextBlock>Tooltip...</TextBlock>
        </ToolTip>
    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```